# Swift: build a dictionary with keys from array1, and values from array2

Tags: swift

Here are 2 arrays: countriesVotedKeys and dictionnaryCountriesVotes.

I need to build a dictionary, whose keys are all the items from countriesVotedKeys, and its values are all the items from dictionnaryCountriesVotes. Both arrays contains same number of elements.
I've tried many things, but none lead to desired result.

```
     for value in self.countriesVotedValues! {
        for key in self.countriesVotedKeys! {
            self.dictionnaryCountriesVotes![key] = value
        }
    }
```

I can clearly see why this code produce bad result: second array is iterated in its entirity at each iteration of first array. I also tried a classical for var i= 0, var j= 0;...... but it seems this kind of syntax is not allowed in swift.
In short, i'm stuck. Again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 4**

```
let keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
let values = [100, 200, 300]

let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))

print(dict)   // "[key1: 100, key3: 300, key2: 200]"
```

---

**Swift 3**

```
var dict: [String: Int] = [:]

for i in 0..<keys.count {
    dict[keys[i]] = values[i]
}
```

Comment: always curious feeling when you've been struggling hours on something, and when someone posts a clean, short answer. It really feels like a god giving an answer to a poor mortal. Thanks for answer, I didn't knew you could access array index in such a way.

Comment: You could also do `for (key,value) in Zip2(keys,values) { myDict[key] = value }` and skip the subscripts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSDictionary`'s convenience initializer:

```
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
let values = [1,2,3]

var dict = NSDictionary(objects: values, forKeys: keys) as [String: Int]
```